# Android Audio Through Earpiece

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to play the audio through the earpiece. I used following code:

```
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

Also declared permission in Manifest.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

The problem is that these lines modify the audio mode for all the apps in my phone and I dont want to revert the settings in the method `onDestroy()`. Is there any way to play the audio from earpiece?

Comment: `AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE` is not an appropriate argument for `setMode`. You should use one of the `MODE_` constants. `USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE` is meant to be used with `adjustSuggestedStreamVolume`.